# Why might python be interpreting my dictionary as a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I'm writing a program to sort through csv files. It is supposed to pull lines from the files and based on whether a "donor" is already in the dictionary, either add the "donor" to the dictionary or append the information in the line to the old value. I'm getting the error statement:

error statement:  File "C:/Users/riley/Desktop/Python Files/MYLATEST1.py", line 27, in 
    donors[donor] = [[data]]
builtins.TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

I'm new to python, but it seems as if python is interpreting my dictionary as a list. Is that what's going on? If so, why? Thanks for any help!

def createDonorDirect():

```
  listoffiles = glob.glob('C:/Users/riley/Desktop/mydata//*.csv') #glob allows you to create a list of files/folders that match wildcard expression in this case all the csv files in the directory

  # Create donors directory
  donors = {}


  for filename in listoffiles:
        with open(filename) as file:

              for line in file:

                    #  line processing stuff
                    data = line.split(',')
                    donor = ''.join(data[3,5,7])


                    # populate data structure 
                    if donor in donors:
                          donors[donor].append(data)
                    else:
                          donors[donor] = [[data]]
```

Comment: `data[3,5,7]` is a much more likely culprit. Something else probably screwed up the error message; maybe you edited the source code after Python opened it or something.

Comment: Any suggestions of how to format data[3,5,7] in a different way, but still have it contain all the necessary information to identify my "donor"?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error is you are assigning donor to tuple value as key, which is wrong here since tuple content multiple values.
sample problem regeneration with code:-

```
>>> data=['HI','Hello','How','are','you','my','name','is']
>>> donor = ''.join(data[3,5,7])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#34>", line 1, in <module>
    donor = ''.join(data[3,5,7])
**TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple**
>>>
```

second simplified code:-

```
>>> data[3,5,7]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#35>", line 1, in <module>
    data[3,5,7]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Answer (score 0):

Tuple declaration can be little confusing sometimes.

For example: `SOME_CONSTANT = 1,` is same as `SOME_CONSTANT = (1, )` . Both are a tuple.

On the other hand, `SOME_CONSTANT = (1)` will be same as `SOME_CONSTANT = 1`. Both are an integer.

In your case you just need to change:

```
donor = ''.join(data[3,5,7])
```

to

```
donor = ''.join(data[3] + data[5] + data[7])
```

Example:

```
data=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']
print ''.join(data[3] + data[5] + data[7])
DFH
```